# Moving Xcode project onto another machine - How do I handle files referenced from outside the project folder?

Tags: xcode, xcode-project

thanks for taking a look.

I had bought the cheapest Mac Mini I could so that I could do some iOS dev, and my project has outgrown it. So I bought a MacBook Pro! It's awesome, uploading my parse cloud code took 15-20 minutes on the mini, and is instantaneous on the MBP.

However, I'm having trouble getting my Xcode project to build.  Some of my frameworks are red in the Project Navigator, and I notice that their paths are /Users/[account name]/Documents/Downloads/[framework files].  It looks like on my mini I had created references instead of copying the files into my project.

I know it's against protocol here, but I haven't attempted much out of fear of breaking something.  I have tried some googling, but I haven't found any relevant info. I may just be searching the wrong stuff, so feel free to mark this as duplicate and send me on the right path.

I'm using github to host a private repo for the project.  What steps should I take to properly move the necessary files into my project folder, re-push the project to github, and pull back onto the other machine?

I am not going to be working from the mini anymore, at least on this project, so if it's easier to copy the file over the the MBP, put it in the project folder, and change the reference or something similar, I can do that. And I haven't made any changes to the code on the MBP, just worked on resetting up signing identities / provisioning profiles. I can always pull the project again if something gets mucked up there, but I'm nervous about changing stuff on the mini, breaking stuff, and not being able to build out my project at all.

Any tips on moving forward before I try stuff myself? Again, sorry that this breaks protocol for posting, I just want to avoid breaking my project... this isn't something a simple undo could fix, and I can't risk losing the entire project because of something stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this:

- make sure all your projects are in source code control and committed -- good practice.
- backup MacBook Pro (time machine), just in case.
- copy the external dependencies over to new MacBook Pro in a way that makes sense.
- one by one, delete the red frameworks and re-add them to the projects. Your choice as to copy vs reference.

Afterwards, I'd *consider* migration to something like Cocoapods for management of dependencies. I say *consider* because that's exactly the state I'm in - considering this option.

This should move you forward fairly safely.  Best of luck!

Comment: Marking it as right, because it is, except that the gosh dang FacebookSDK is ridiculously terrible in this case.... Can't build out my project because FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h isn't found, which seems to be a common issue with only one common solution (basically this one) that rarely seems to work. Endlessly frustrating.  Other frameworks/files worked fine.